# Kivy issue while importing the module "pandasgui". It shows a black screen and buttons get frozen

Tags: python, pandas, kivy, kivymd

Using the code below I can press a button in Kivy and open, outside of kivy, an external gui ('pandasgui') that is great to  display pandas dataframe.

Unfortunately if I import the module "pandasgui" at the beginning, kivy shows a black screen, that's why I'm importing the module inside the function.

At the moment the code works fine, because when you press the "Show Dataframe" button, the dataframe shows up in the external "pandasgui" GUI.

Nevertheless, when the "pandasgui" GUI is opened the "Show Dataframe" button freezes sometimes (you can see the white dot that keep steady on the button.. something is not working here for sure). Even if I close the "pandasgui" GUI, the "Show Dataframe" keep to be freezed or showing such white dot.

How can I fix it?

I wonder also why, if I import the "pandasgui" module at the beginning of the code kivy shows a black screen. I've never saw such behavior before.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


KV = '''
Screen:           
    MDRaisedButton:         
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}           
        text: "Show Dataframe"
        on_release: app.showDF()  
        
    MDRaisedButton:         
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}    
        text: "Press to print <Hello World>"
        on_release: app.generalPrinting()       
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def showDF(self):
        # import modules
        from pandasgui import show
        import pandas as pd
        #Create dataframe
        d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        #Show DF
        gui = show(df) # open in pandasGUI

    def generalPrinting(self):
        print("Hello World")

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Example().run()
```

Comment: It sounds like the pandasgui module starts its own eventloop, which blocks the rest of the code in your file from continuing. If you put a print call just after you run `show()`, do you ever see the result of that print?

Comment: @inclement yes you can see the result of the print function.Nevertheless you still see the white circle on the kivy button as you can see in this picture: https://prnt.sc/vrf8e3

Comment: It still looks like the kivy gui is frozen, even if the code isn't. Maybe pandasgui interferes with the gl context or something. Do the buttons still work if you click them, even if you can't see a change in the gui?

Comment: @inclement yes buttons still work, but in a more complex gui everything become unstable.  When the module pandasgui get imported this behaviour happens. Pandasgui is defintely one of the best gui for data visualization, so it's so weird that there is such conflict with kivy.... Some other ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You can try basic things like running pandasgui in a thread, but if it's messing up the gl context that probably won't work. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong as I wouldn't expect the qt drawing to interact with kivy.

Comment: @inclement could you please show me how can I edit my code in order to run pandasgui in a thread? Thanks in advance